# Auto Search using Php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

while i am making the point of sale system i ran in to problem with the search.
when i enter the product code on the product code textbox it automatically Search and display product name and price in to the relevant textboxes using `ajax` and `jquery` and `php`. what i tried code i attached below. i didn't get any answer while i ran the code.please read the below code and get good solution for me as soon as possible.

**Form Design**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Code</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_code" name="product_code" placeholder="Product Code" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name" placeholder="product_name " required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price" name="price" placeholder="price" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**AJAX**

```
    function getProductcode() {
        $('#product_code').empty();

        $("#product_code").keyup(function(e) {
                var q = $("#product_code").val();


                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '../php/project_module/get_purchase.php',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        async: false,
                        success: function(data) {

                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                $('#product_code').append($("<option/>", {
                                    value: data[i].product_id,
                                    text: data[i].product_name,


                                }));
                            }
                            data: {
                                    product_code: $('#product_code').val()
                                },

                        }
                    },

                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {

                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                        //
                    }

                });
        }

**get_purchase.php**

    $product_code = $_POST["product_code"];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select  product_id,product_name,barcode,category,description,warrenty,product_condition,price_retail,
                       price_cost,discount,reorderlevel,brand
         from product  where barcode = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $product_code);
    $stmt->bind_result($product_id,$product_name,$price);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
            $output[] = array ("product_id"=>$product_id,"product_name"=>$product_name,"price_retail"=>$price);
        }
        echo json_encode( $output );
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Is the query running fine? It should not be too difficult for you to debug `get_purchase.php` to see whether the data is properly aggregated and written to an array or whether you have a problem in displaying the result of that array in your frontend

Comment: yes i checked sir database query running fine.i checked on mysql. i have problem with ajex passing the value can you check sir

Comment: So the result generated through PHP is definitely okay?

Comment: yes sir  . i am waiting for the result

Comment: As far as I can see, your JS code is broken. Why is there a `data` key within your `success` function?

Comment: yes. i  just see the internet and wrote sir. if there is a problem on that then please help me correct. please rewrite the ajex code its more help for me to study.

Comment: sir i have tried the code what you have typed but no answer displayed but no errors shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data attribute is in the wrong place of the ajax configuration.

Here is a revised version

Add this to your HTML

```
<p id="output"></p>
```

And this as your getProductCode() definition

```
function getProductcode() {
  $("#product_code").empty();

  $("#product_code").keyup(function(e) {
    var q = $("#product_code").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../php/project_module/get_purchase.php",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: { product_code: $("#product_code").val() },
      success: function(data) {
        if(typeof data === 'undefined'){
          return
        }
        $("#output").val(data[0].product_id + " : "  +data[0].product_name)
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I pasted your code in my editor (VS Code) and it gave helpful syntax errors. Maybe it would be a good idea to look into editors with syntax highlighting and checking capabilities?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: showModal is not defined. Error i got.   sir what i need is when i Enter the Product Code on the Product Code textbox it automatically Search and display product name and price in to the relevant textboxs

Comment: showModal isn't used inside this revised code, and the code you've shown. It seems a showModal() function is being called without it being defined. Please check your code for this function and make sure it is defined.

Comment: i have edited your code above sir. not combo box . textboxs. i have put the textbox name with in the forloop result is diplay on the textboxs.  when i Enter the Product Code on the Product Code textbox it automatically Search and display product name and price in to the relevant

Comment: Well, that means it's almost working! Just create another <select> element inside your html like <select id="output"></select>. and use $("#output") to append <option/>s to instead of $("#product_code")

Comment: can you write the ajex code sir. no combo box sir .  when i Enter the Product Code on the Product Code textbox it automatically Search and display product name and price in to the relevant that only i need. using $("#product_code").keyup(function(e)

Comment: if you write the ajex code fully it is easy for understand thanks.